# Read after specific text and stop reading when it reaches a empty line and then write it to output file

Tags: text, vbscript

Currently I only can read and write everything from my input file to the output file. But I only want to read the line after book1|book2|book3 and stop reading when it reaches a empty line, after that write to the output file based on what it reads. I have found this code `nStr(strLine, sStringToFind)`, but I don't know if it will work properly here, or how to use it.

**My input file**
[image]

**My current output based on my codes**
[image]

**This is the output I want to achieve**
[image]

```
 Set objWorkbook = objFSO2.OpenTextFile(inputFilePath)

              Dim strLine
              Dim intLineCounter

              intLineCounter = 0    

              Do Until objWorkbook.AtEndOfStream

              strLine = objWorkbook.ReadLine

              objFile.WriteLine(strLine) 

              intLineCounter = intLineCounter + 1
              Loop
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Copy part of input file to output file - top level structure:

1. Preparations
2. Read/Write Loop
3. CleanUp

Preparations: open files and setup state variable to indicate writing

1. Set tsIn = oFS.OpenTextFile(...)
2. Set tsOut = oFS.CreateTextFile(...)
3. bWrite = False

CleanUp: close the files

1. tsOut.Close
2. tsIn.Close

Read/Write Loop

```
Do Until tsIn.AtEndOfStream
   sLine = tsIn.ReadLine()
   ... Kernel ...
Loop
```

Interesting events

1. sLine = "book1|book2|book3" ==> write from next line on
2. sLine = "" **after** event 1 ==> done

Kernel:

```
If sLine = "book1|book2|book3" Then
   bWrite = True
Else
   If bWrite Then
      If sLine = "" Then
         Exit Do
      Else
         tsOut.WriteLine sLine
      End If
   End If
End If
```

**Update wrt @Hackoo's answer:**

A **decent** implementation of the above plan:

```
Option Explicit

Dim oFS    : Set oFS   = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
Dim tsIn   : Set tsIn  = oFS.OpenTextFile("..\data\25301708.txt")
Dim tsOut  : Set tsOut = oFS.CreateTextFile("..\data\25301708-out.txt")
Dim bWrite : bWrite    = False
Dim sLine

Do Until tsIn.AtEndOfStream
   sLine = tsIn.ReadLine()
   If sLine = "book1|book2|book3" Then
      bWrite = True
   Else
      If bWrite Then
         If sLine = "" Then
            Exit Do
         Else
            tsOut.WriteLine sLine
         End If
      End If
   End If
Loop

tsOut.Close
tsIn.Close
```

Answer (score 2):

Try out this code :

```
Option Explicit
Dim Titre,Data,s,LogFile,ws,fso,Result,Lines,Line
Set fso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
Set ws = CreateObject("Wscript.Shell")
LogFile = Left(Wscript.ScriptFullName,InstrRev(Wscript.ScriptFullName, ".")) & "txt"
if fso.FileExists(LogFile) Then 
    fso.DeleteFile LogFile
end If
Data = ReadFileText("file.txt")
Result = Between_Ands(Data,"book1|book2|book3","fax1|fax2|fax3")
Lines = Split(Result,vbCrLf)
For Each Line In Lines
    If Len(Line) > 0 Then
        WriteLog Line,LogFile
    end if
Next
ws.Run LogFile,1,False
'**********************************************************************************************
Function Between_Ands(ByVal Full_String, ByVal First_Delimiter, ByVal Second_Delimiter)
    Dim Pos,Pos2
    Pos = InStr(Full_String, First_Delimiter)
    Pos2 = InStr(Full_String, Second_Delimiter)
    If Pos = 0 Or Pos2 = 0 Then
        Between_Ands = "Missing Delimiter"
        Exit Function
    End If
    Between_Ands = Mid(Full_String, Pos + Len(First_Delimiter), Pos2 - (Pos + Len(First_Delimiter)))
End Function
'***********************************************************************************************
Function ReadFileText(sFile)
    Dim objFSO,oTS,sText
    Set objFSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
    If Not objFSO.FileExists(sFile) Then
        MsgBox "CRITICAL ERROR " & VbCrLF & "The File "& DblQuote(sFile) & " dosen't exists !",VbCritical,"CRITICAL ERROR"
        Wscript.Quit
    Else
        Set oTS = objFSO.OpenTextFile(sFile)
        sText = oTS.ReadAll
        oTS.close
        set oTS = nothing
        Set objFSO = nothing
        ReadFileText = sText
    End if
End Function 
'***********************************************************************************************
Sub WriteLog(strText,LogFile)
    Dim fs,ts 
    Const ForAppending = 8
    Set fs = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
    Set ts = fs.OpenTextFile(LogFile,ForAppending,True)
    ts.WriteLine strText
    ts.Close
End Sub
'************************************************************************************************
Function DblQuote(Str)
    DblQuote = Chr(34) & Str & Chr(34)
End Function
'**********************************************************************************************
```

With the solution proposed by **Ekkehard.Horner**

You have to do like this :

```
Option Explicit
Dim Titre,Data,s,LogFile,ws,fso,Result,Lines,Line,bWrite
Set fso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
Set ws = CreateObject("Wscript.Shell")
bWrite = False
LogFile = Left(Wscript.ScriptFullName,InstrRev(Wscript.ScriptFullName, ".")) & "txt"
if fso.FileExists(LogFile) Then 
    fso.DeleteFile LogFile
end If
Data = ReadFileText("file.txt")
Lines = Split(Data,vbCrLf)
For Each Line In Lines
    If Line = "book1|book2|book3" Then
        bWrite = True
    Else
        If bWrite Then
            If Line = "" Then
                Exit For
            Else
                WriteLog Line,LogFile
            End If
        End if
    End if
Next
ws.Run LogFile,1,False
'***********************************************************************************************
    Function ReadFileText(sFile)
        Dim objFSO,oTS,sText
        Set objFSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
        If Not objFSO.FileExists(sFile) Then
            MsgBox "CRITICAL ERROR " & VbCrLF & "The File "& DblQuote(sFile) & " dosen't exists !",VbCritical,"CRITICAL ERROR"
            Wscript.Quit
        Else
            Set oTS = objFSO.OpenTextFile(sFile)
            sText = oTS.ReadAll
            oTS.close
            set oTS = nothing
            Set objFSO = nothing
            ReadFileText = sText
        End if
    End Function 
'***********************************************************************************************
    Sub WriteLog(strText,LogFile)
        Dim fs,ts 
        Const ForAppending = 8
        Set fs = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
        Set ts = fs.OpenTextFile(LogFile,ForAppending,True)
        ts.WriteLine strText
        ts.Close
    End Sub
'************************************************************************************************
    Function DblQuote(Str)
        DblQuote = Chr(34) & Str & Chr(34)
    End Function
'**********************************************************************************************
```

Answer (score 0):

I found myself needing a similar script tonight. `Instr` acts like boolean when just searching for a string, even though it technically gives you the position of the match (in the other string you're searching). I find it a little more flexible too (than doing a straight comparison with equals). `Else If` consolidates the main logic:

```
Const ForReading = 1, ForWriting = 2, ForAppending = 8

strInFile = "inFile.txt" 'Put a full path if you want
strOutFile = "outFile.txt" 

Set objFS = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
Set objInFile = objFS.OpenTextFile(strInFile, ForReading)
Set objOutFile = objFS.OpenTextFile(strOutFile, ForWriting, True)
writeNow = false

Do Until objInFile.AtEndOfStream
   sReadLine = objInFile.ReadLine()

    If instr(sReadLine, "book1|book2|book3") Then
        writeNow = true                'We exit the if statement here ready to write on the next loop
    ElseIf (writeNow AND Trim(sReadLine) = "") Then
        Exit Do                        'We exit the loop, finished writing
    ElseIf writeNow Then
        objOutFile.WriteLine sReadLine 'Otherwise, we write
    End If
Loop

objOutFile.Close
objInFile.Close
```

Long live VBScript!